# benchmarking django application with many simultaneously requests like ab

Tags: python, django, profiling, benchmarking

I have a django application on an apache server on OpenShift and want to test its performance that is how much does it take to process a request (GET or POST) and return the response to user.

I want to be able to test it while setting the number of requests for the page I am benchmarking and how many of them will be done simultaneously just like ab does.

I tried to use ab but I cannot use it for pages that need authentication and logged in user to be shown. Is there a tool to help me automate some of these testes? I want the tool to be able to run outside the django environment, because I would like my employer to be able to run it from his PC.

What would you suggest? Some of the pages I want to test also do some model search and return some results and they also upload some pictures. I would like to be able to automate and measure these too.

Comment: What kind of authentication do you use ?

Comment: I am using django's session authentication as you correctly guessed on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Django's [SessionMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/middleware/#module-django.contrib.sessions.middleware), `ab` is able to test urls that need authentication. Django uses an ID stored in cookies (in user side) for authenticate users. An example of `ab` authenticated request:

```
ab -C sessionid=YourTokenID https://yourwebsite.org
```

- `sessionid` is the cookie name
- `YourTokenID` can be find easily with a browser or the model `django.contrib.sessions.models.Session`

References:

- [ab documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html)
- [Django session documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/)

Comment: This is my command ab -c 100 -n 1000 -C sessionid=myTokenID -C  csrftoken=myCSRFTOKEN http://127.0.0.1:8000/crm/calendar/fullcalendar/
but I get a socket error from server...Running it on django's development and then on apache. Does this matter?

Comment: Django development server is not made for. I think it can't support load and raises socketError.

Comment: Thank you on last thing if you might know...I try to post on a url, after i obtained my sessionid and csrfid but I still get a 403 status code from server. What could be the fault?post_data file contains the following line doctor=2&csrfmiddlewaretoken=mytoken

Comment: Trouble is I thinks crsf_token

Comment: I have added it...guess it needs to be added differently...I don't know...Have to find out though :)